# Python super() and inherited class directory location

Tags: python, structure

I'm trying to figure out how get a system I'm using for a Theme manager for UI project I'm working on to work correctly.

Example:

File Structure:

```
element.py    - class Element()
button.py     - class Button(Element)
text.py       - class Text(Element)
input/text.py - class Text(Element)
```

I use class-name for different properties in my theme. (Similar to CSS)

So 'element' could have the text color be white.

I currently have all UI elements inherit from 'Element' and using:

```
self.__class__.__name__.lower()
```

This is working for 'Button' and 'Element', the problem comes into play for input.text vs text. Text is for all uses of displaying text so it's in almost all Elements, but the input.text class is named Text as well is used for Text Input and I want to use a property selector like 'input.text' instead of just 'text' that I get now for it with the class.name.

I'm trying to set this up in the end so it has a plugin system for others to add elements and being able to use the directory structure as part of the property selector.

For example:

```
Button class: button
Text class: text
Text Input class: text, but in the directory 'input'
```

I am trying to figure out how to get python to check if 'self' in element from a super() call is in a directory below where 'element.py' is. Which would add on the directory name to the class name for the properties it checks against.

End result would be:

```
element
button
text
input.text
```

TLDR: I need to know how to check if an inherited class is in a different directory than the base class and what that directory is called.

Thanks for any assistance in figuring this out.

Comment: I don't believe what you're trying to do is easy to implement or a good idea in general. I recommend (in no particular order) 1) Rename the class in input/text.py to `InputText`, 2) Solely base a class name based on the file path and name (which doesn't feel like a good idea but is better than using the class name and the file path), or 3) default to the class name but allow classes to override the name by specifying an optional field somewhere. Please edit your question accordingly if you'd like some help with one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found out how to do it the way I wanted to. Just answering the question, while I also think on the comment from @supersam654.

I was able to find out how to get the path from an inherited class with:

```
import os, sys

el = os.path.dirname(sys.modules[self.__class__.__module__].__file__).split('/')
base = os.path.dirname(__file__).split('/')
for i in base:
  el.remove(i)
```

Anything left over in 'el' will have individual directory names that I can use.